# Why is my level decreasing during inactivity?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

Why does my avatar's level decrease over time of not playing? What can I do to stop this from happening again to my lesser accounts.

Comment: Do you mean "Why is my experience decreasing"? Some MMOs have you lose EXP when you die.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your characters do not lose experience when you do not play for a long time. I have not played characters on one server for years now, and they have remained at the same level when I look at them on the LOTRO website. You may not remember what level your characters were at, but again, there is no penalty for not logging in for a long time.

Comment: Indeed.  I just logged back in again for the first time in years.  My characters were still 65, which was max level when I left.

Comment: Yeah, the level cap has increased by 20 since that time. No penalty for dying or inactivity has been added since Mirkwood, though there is no dread from defeat anymore